# How to save nested array objects to mongo db via mongoose?

Tags: mongoose-schema

Im using postman to send a POST request to my node express server then with that data, im creating a new mongoose model instance and save it to the db but its not what i was expecting.

The exercises field is empty and inside that array of objects, i have another nested array of objects (set) which i dont know how to add data into there and save the entire workout document to the database.

Sorry if i dont make much sense,  i hope everything below is clear enough.

Please help. Thank you

This is the data im sending

```
{
"title": "Chest (Volume)",
"exercises": [
    {
        "name": "Bench Press",
        "note": "Did dumbells instead",
        "sets": [
            {
                "set": 1,
                "weight": 60,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 7.5
            },
            {
                "set": 2,
                "weight": 65,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 8
            },
            {
                "set": 3,
                "weight": 70,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 8.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Incline Press",
        "note": "It's heavy mate!",
        "sets": [
            {
                "set": 1,
                "weight": 60,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 7.5
            },
            {
                "set": 2,
                "weight": 65,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 8
            },
            {
                "set": 3,
                "weight": 70,
                "rep": 10,
                "rpe": 8.5
            }
        ]
    }
],
  "user": "60966f1e7c0006044efe173c"
}
```

### Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const WorkoutSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    exercise: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          required: true
        },
        note: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          required: true
        },
        sets: [
          {
            type: Number,
            required: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    user: {
      required: true,
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
    },
    {
      timestamps: true
     }
    );

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', WorkoutSchema);
```

### My Controller

```
const createWorkout = async (req, res) => {
    try {
       const workout = new Workout({
       title: req.body.title,
       exercises: req.body.exercises,
       user: req.body.user
     });
    
       await workout.save();
       res.send(workout);
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(error);
     }
    };
```

### Postman Response

[image]

Comment: Typo error: "exercises" and "exercise" used; use one only.